# Is it possible to fork a repository over a specific tag in Git? How can I do it?

Tags: git, github

I am following and using a very interesting project on GitHub to implement Chatbots, but the new version made many changes, which can be considered totally incompatible with the previous version.

Is there a way to make a fork of the project, but of a specific tag?

Thank you.

Comment: *Fork* is a GitHub concept, so it's defined by them, not by Git; but in practice a fork is a mirror clone plus some behind-the-scenes linkage so that it takes almost no space in GitHub's servers. That means you get *all* the tags and branches. You can then delete most tags and branches from your clone, but your clone remains linked behind-the-scenes for pull-request purposes. If you don't want that either, you must not use GitHub's "fork" operation.

Comment: @torek Thank you for your comment.